# Leer .docx con .read() produce un error en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy intentando subir un archivo a Dropbox, produce un error. El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('mi_codigo_de_dropbox')
nombreArchivo = 'Reporte 49.docx'
path = '/machineAR/' + nombreArchivo
with open(nombreArchivo, 'r') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), path)
```

Lo que pasa, es que el modulo `.read()` me arroja el siguiente error:

`'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 10-11: invalid continuation type`

Ya he probado con varios tipos de archivos, .docx vacíos e incluso con archivos .png y no funciona.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion fue:

```
import dropbox

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('mi_codigo_de_dropbox')
nombreArchivo = 'Reporte 49.docx'
path = '/machineAR/' + nombreArchivo
with open(nombreArchivo, 'rb') as f:
    dbx.files_upload(f.read(), path)
```